# How do I style the background of QWidget in a styled QFrame?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtstylesheets

I have an image I want as the as the background of the border of my Qframe widget. I want the treewidget inside the frame to have a background color which takes precedent over the frame image. My attempt so far has got areas under the checkbox which arent styled by the parent/child treewidgetitems. How do I make all the background area within the frame border the same color?

[image: Attempt so far pic]

```
import PyQt5.QtGui
import PyQt5.QtWidgets
import PyQt5.QtCore

import sys

foods = [['Cookie dough', '5.2'],
         ['Hummus', '7.9'],
         ['Spaghetti', '9.92'],
         ['Dal makhani', '4.2'],
         ['Chocolate whipped cream', '1.2']]

class TreeWidget(PyQt5.QtWidgets.QTreeWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        
    
        for product, price in foods:
            parent = PyQt5.QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem([product])
            parent.setBackground(0, PyQt5.QtGui.QBrush(PyQt5.QtGui.QColor('#e6dddc')))
            parent.setFlags(parent.flags() | PyQt5.QtCore.Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable)
            parent.setTextAlignment(PyQt5.QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft, PyQt5.QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft)
            check_state = PyQt5.QtCore.Qt.Checked
            parent.setCheckState(0, check_state)
            
            child = PyQt5.QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem([price])
            child.setBackground(0, PyQt5.QtGui.QBrush(PyQt5.QtGui.QColor('#e6dddc')))
            parent.addChild(child)
            
            self.addTopLevelItem(parent)
            
        self.setRootIsDecorated(False)
        self.setHeaderHidden(True)
        self.expandAll()
        
        
class Section(PyQt5.QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setStyleSheet("QFrame {background-image: url('assets/wrap3.jpeg')}")
        
        layout = PyQt5.QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        
        self.treeWidget = TreeWidget()
        
        self.frame = PyQt5.QtWidgets.QFrame()
        self.frame.setFrameShape(PyQt5.QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame.setFrameShadow(PyQt5.QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        tree_layout = PyQt5.QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.frame)
        tree_layout.addWidget(self.treeWidget)

        layout.addWidget(self.frame,0,0)
        self.setLayout(layout)

            
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = PyQt5.QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Section()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[The artistic vision looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BGSOe.png)

Comment: Do you mean that you want the background visible only for the parent QFrame, but *not* for the background of the tree view, which will have its own color?

Comment: Your question is unclear, could you put a picture of what you want to get

Comment: @eyllanesc see update for intention. Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that QTreeWidget inherits from QFrame (the inheritance is QTreeWidget > QTreeView > QAbstractItemView > QAbstractScrollArea > QFrame), so your stylesheet is actually applied not only on the "container" frame, but on the tree view also.

The solution in this case is to properly use [stylesheet selectors](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-syntax.html#selector-types). In this simple case, the *class selector* would be enough (notice the period before `QFrame`):

```
self.setStyleSheet(".QFrame {background-image: url('assets/wrap3.jpeg')}")
```

This will ensure that only QFrame widgets (and not QFrame subclasses) will have that background.

Setting the background color on the tree is a bit different, and it depends on the system/style in use: you could set the background for TreeWidget (your class) in the stylesheet, but that could create some issues in certain cases, most importantly for the checkboxes background.
An alternative is to change the palette for the `Base` role, which is the color used for the background of item views (sometimes used also for the actual item background, others as *source* color for them):

```
        palette = self.treeWidget.palette()
        palette.setColor(palette.Base, PyQt5.QtGui.QColor(24, 143, 255))
        self.treeWidget.setPalette(palette)
```

Comment: thanks musica. makes sense. nice and easy to fix.

Comment: @wxecqz123 you're welcome. Remember that if an answer solves your problem you should mark it as accepted by clicking on the gray tick mark on its left.